# Does the CSRF apply for Normal javascript & .net core API application?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, csrf, owasp

I have the general MVC application which renders the views. From the UI, I directly call my .NET Core API which does all the tasks of GET, POST, PUT & DELETE of resources.

I want to know if somehow cross-site request forgery is applicable in my scenario, If Yes then the token generated via normal MVC application gets validated in .NET Core API?  Which approach Should I follow to implement cross-site request forgery in my scenario.

Comment: Web API should use somekind of authorization token instead CSRF. CSRF by essence is to prevent someone with `<form>` tag on the other side of domain sending fake requests to your pages. if you really want to make it secure, try to check on [JWE](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-jose-json-web-encryption), it had [.Net implementation on github by Jose](https://github.com/dvsekhvalnov/jose-jwt/blob/master/jose-jwt/JWT.cs)

Answer (score 0):

Cross-site request forgery only apllies when you are making requests from onde domain to another domain.

If your APIs are on the same domain as your front-end source, then you don't need to worry about CORS.

Here's a good example: https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: Yes agree with your point Carlos but I have enabled the CORS on my .net core API so as we are also selling these APIs to the third party. So Does them make vulnerable if the request comes from another origin?

Comment: CSRF is not only applicable when CORS is in play, the attacker does not need the response, they only need the request to execute, they don't care about the response at all, and CORS only protects the reponse from being read.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not already written yor entire appication, then your best bet is to use the in built MVC protection. Please read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/xsrfcsrf-prevention-in-aspnet-mvc-and-web-pages on this front, this article may not be the most up to date though!

If you've already written your application (or it is otherwise infeasible to apply this protection to every incoming request) then your best bet is to implement some generic javscript which lives on the default razor layout (and therefore exists on every page) which will read a cookie value and implement double submit cookie validation. Ideally the value of this cookie would come from, and be verified by a server side session, this prevents any third party from issuing requests from CURL and such without authentication. If the value is generated client side (using `window.crypto`) then I'd argue your general user would be safe, but requests can still be issued by applications such as CURL that will pass the check (because there is no server side validation!).

Or otherwise implement referer/Origin header defences, which are not ideal but can only really be bested if your user is using an exploitable user agent.

Both of the above approaches are detailed by OWASP here https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet and please take note, you must ALWAYS worry about CSRF, since browsers do nothing to prevent you from it, and the attacker does not necesarily need the response, they only need the required action to execute. CORS etc. will only prevent the attacker from reading the response (e.g. 200 OK UserDeletion) but will not prevent the request from actually being fulfilled in the first place (e.g. the User has actually been deleted!)

Comment: why do i feel this proposal strayed too far from God. well, is not being able to be called independent from session or csrf is the point of web api - with CORS and all about like the comment onCarlos Coelho's post? cmiiw.

Comment: I don't see any mention of Web Api here, as far as I'm concerned this question is about an MVC application using Session auth, and has nothing to do with a Web Api implemented using OAuth2 or such.

Comment: *From the UI, I directly call my **.NET Core API** which does all the tasks of GET, POST, PUT & DELETE of resources.*

Comment: MVC controllers are an API, and they can do all of those things...The default method of authentication for such controllers is Session auth.